# Dielectric wave guides vs metallic wave guides

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, waveguide

I have a couples of questions regarding wave guides. First of all, why are dielectric wave guides better than metallic wave guides for wavelengths in the visible spectrum? Also, for non-ideal metallic wave guides, which attenuation constant is easier to minimize, $\alpha_c$ or $\alpha_d$? My intuition would be that it would be easier to have a medium close to a perfect dielectric rather than a perfect conductor but I can't really explain why.

Comment: You have to define what you mean by $\alpha_c$ and $\alpha_d$ before anybody can answer that part of your question.

Answer (score 3):

They are *better* already in the mm-wave region but in the optical region there are two main  reasons:

1. glass is an astonishingly low loss material, abundant and
   relatively easy to manufacture,
2. a closed metallic waveguide would have to have a cross sectional
   diameter less than a wavelength to ensure singe mode propagation.
   How would that be manufactured  over thousands of miles? If you go
   by the way of an open guide such as the Goubau line then you still
   have to deal with metallic loss and you still have to coat it with a
   dielectric.

Before fiber optics, in the 50's and 60's Bell Labs was seriously investing and experimenting with the so-called $TE_{01}$ mode of the circular waveguide to use it for long distances below 30GHz. This mode has a very unusual propagation property: the higher the frequency of operation is the more concentrated the field becomes in the middle, hence its wall losses decrease. Unfortunately one has to deal with various *mode losses* as this $TE_{01}$ is **not** the fundamental mode of the pipe, hence the helical (!) wall construction to suppress spurious modes of propagation. The money and experimentation ended almost the day of appearance of low loss fiber glass...

And to you other question, if the wall losses are significant then the shape of the field, that is the mode, changes too. In general and *theoretically* speaking, it is just easier to deal with a uniform loss imparted by the dielectric.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I can understand why they are better from an engineering perspective. So basically you'll get more losses in a metallic wave guide than you would for a dielectric. I don't understand why they would be better for this specific region of the spectrum though. I have heard that metallic wave guides are good for radio waves for example. So at what point does the dielectric wave guide become a better option? More specifically, what is the correlation between the effectiveness of a certain type of wave guide and the wavelength of the signal you want to pass through it?

Comment: There is no "one" point. Somewhere around 20-30GHz engineers *try* to avoid metal as it gets lossier than something having the same function in dielectric in various applications. You can still find closed waveguides up to 120GHz or so, always plated with gold, unavoidable to remove heat from amplifiers/oscillators, but beyond that it is impractical aside form being a heatsink. Instead you have dielectric slabs ("image guide"), quasi optics (dielectric lenses), dieletric/metal suspended guides, etc.